# Applying transforms from DataTemplates in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate

I've created a DataTemplate for my objects in a `ResourceDictionary` file. The template is basically an image that is loaded from the disk. Now, what happens is that I want to align the image to a specific point on my Canvas but not by its upper left point but its center point, that's why I want to apply a translate transform for `X = -Width / 2` and 
`Y = -Height / 2` but I don't know how to apply them via the DataTemplate.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using databinding on Canvas' the AttachedProperties and an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to  transform the offsets to whatever you want.

For instance:

```
class ImageToCanvasConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return -(int)value / 2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Two-way binding not supported
        throw new InvalidOperationException(); 
    }
}

<Grid.Resources>
    <myAssembly:ImageToCanvasConverter x:Key="imageToCanvasConverter" />
    <DataTemplate ...>
        <Image Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource imageToCanvasConverter}, Mode=OneTime}"
               Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource imageToCanvasConverter}, Mode=OneTime}"
               ... />
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: I did it another way (by creating a property for the X and Y offsets and simply binding it to a `Image.RenderTransform`, but I guess your way of using converters could work just as good. I don't know converters that well so that'll be my next step. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can take the advantage of using loaded event on the data template child
Example:

if you are using grid as data template content

```
<DataTemplate>
 <Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
   <Image></Image>
 </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

you can write the transformation code in the .cs file using sender object.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will definitely try that for other stuff I need events for.